# TypeScript w/ React: How do I properly type the updater returned by `useState` when passing it to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a `Modal` component that accepts a `boolean` and a callback as its props. The callback is the function used for toggle the visibility of the `Modal`. And that callback is the updater returned from `useState` in the parent component

```
interface ModalProps {
  visible: boolean;
  setVisibility: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal visible={visibility} setVisibility={setVisibility} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ visible, setVisibility }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {visible.toString()}
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setVisibility(!visible);
        }}
      >
        toggle visibility
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My question is, how should I type this `setVisibility` prop for `Modal`? Currently I typed it as  `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;` because that seems to be the correct type for the updater from    `const [visibility, setVisibility] = React.useState(false);`. However I tried to change the callback to some other random function such as

```
      <Modal visible={visibility} setVisibility={console.log} />
```

or

```
      <Modal visible={visibility} setVisibility={() => {}} />
```

There is not TS compiler errors raised. That got me wondering if I typed the prop correctly and how should I type it?

Comment: `console.log` or `() => {}` will happily accept a parameter of type `boolean` or `(v: boolean) => boolean` without a problem, what makes you think that type is incorrect?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yea I thought the typing would only make the parameter more specific. So do you think it is right to type it this way though?

Comment: It is the correct type, yes. That is the same type that `@types/react` uses to annotate `setState()` functions returned by `useState()`