# Type for the setState function of the useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, use-state

I'm converting my React project to Typescript.

I have this piece of state:

**AdminBlogPostContainer.tsx**

```
const [blogPost,setBlogPost] = useState<null | BLOGPOST>(null);

return(
  <AdminBlogPostPage
    blogPost={blogPost as BLOGPOST}
    setBlogPost={setBlogPost}
  />
);
```

**AdminBlogPostPage.tsx**

```
interface AdminBlogPostPage {
  blogPost: BLOGPOST,
  setBlogPost:            // <---- WHAT SHOULD I USE AS TYPE HERE ?
}

const AdminBlogPostPage: React.FC<AdminBlogPostPage> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering AdminBlogPostPage...");

  return(
    // ...
  );
};

export default AdminBlogPostPage;
```

This is the error message:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't change parent state from children anyway

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But regardless of whether I should be changing state from parent on children, does anybody know what type I should use for the `setState` function in that case?

Comment: Can't close as a duplicate since the answer is not accepted, but otherwise should be... https://stackoverflow.com/q/63551792

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks!! That is what I was looking for. So in my case I should use: `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<null | BLOGPOST>>` ? Feel free to answer here and I'll accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Appreciate the accepted answer, went ahead and deleted my answer from the other post and made this the canonical duplicate instead.

Comment: Quick example for visitors coming here from Google: `const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Array<Todo>>([])`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's start with some relevant type definitions from [`@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts).

```
declare namespace React {
    // ...
    type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
    // ...
    type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
    // ...
    function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
    // ...
}
```

From this we can already deduce the type of `setBlogPost` in the statement

```
const [blogPost, setBlogPost] = useState<null | BLOGPOST>(null);
```

which is `Dispatch<SetStateAction<null | BLOGPOST>>`, but let's break that down to see what each part means.

```
setBlogPost: (value: null | BLOGPOST | ((prevState: null | BLOGPOST) => null | BLOGPOST)) => void;
```

Digesting that one piece at a time working from the outside in, we get the following explanation:

- #### `setBlogPost: (value: ...) => void`

  `setBlogPost` is a function that accepts a parameter `value` and returns `void`.

  - #### `value: null | BLOGPOST | ((prevState: ...) => null | BLOGPOST)`

    `value` is either `null`, a `BLOGPOST`, or a function that accepts a parameter `prevState` and returns `null` or a `BLOGPOST`.

    - #### `prevState: null | BLOGPOST`

      `prevState` is either `null` or a `BLOGPOST`.

Answer (score -1):

```
interface AdminBlogPostPage {
  blogPost: BLOGPOST;
  setBlogPost: Function;            // <---- You may use the Function type here
}
```

Comment: Typescript errors out and does not suggest this OOTB:

Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.
It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.
If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function